# cups filter - need to allow "others" read permission

Tags: c++, qt, printing, io, cups

I have a Qt app that prints to a file in Linux using cups... and it needs to be able to read that file after printing. I am using a custom filter that has a "File=" option.

Unfortunately printing to a file creates a lp-owned file

```
-rw------- 1 lp      lp      2405465 Nov 11 12:17 abcd.ps
```

If I create a file ahead of time and attempt to print, printing fails. Lots of troubleshooting made me realize (guess) that it is because of the ownership.

How can I set permissions in the cups filter to have "group" and "others" read permission ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a file in Qt app, gave it rw permission for "group" and "others"

cups was able to write to it, and so was my app.

(Would be nice to change the custom filter to allow "others" permission, at least "r" but I have not found anything in the documentation yet on how to do that)